# Optimizing DataTable Data loading

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to load data into datatable. Currently, for loading 14000 rows and 3 columns, it is taking 2 mins. I want to optimize this.

sortedDates size is 14K rows.

```
this.TimeSeriesDataTable.BeginLoadData();
foreach (var date in sortedDates)
{
    DataRow newRow = this.TimeSeriesDataTable.NewRow();

    newRow["Dates"] = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    // Each Series represent columns. No of cols is based on user selection.        
    foreach (TimeSeries sr in series) 
    {
        // I am getting JSON structure with sep array of Dates/Values. 
        // I am creating this dic by zipping the 2 list. 
        Dictionary<int, double> DateValuesMap = sr.DatesValuesDic; 
        double val;
        double seriesValue = DateValuesMap.TryGetValue(date, out val) ? val :  Constants.NAValue;
        if (!isNA(seriesValue)) newRow[sr.Label] = seriesValue;
        else newRow[sr.Label] = Constants.NAValue;
        newRow[sr.Label] = seriesValue;
    }
    this.TimeSeriesDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
this.TimeSeriesDataTable.EndLoadData();
```

How can I optimize this? Is there any better way to do this? Should I not be using DataTable at all?

Comment: What is the end result here? What is the goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I doubt that loading 14k rows does take 2 minutes. Have you measured that the expensive part is not what   you've commented as "doing some simple processing"?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, can `Thread.Sleep(100);` count as simple?

Comment: So this is taking 2 mins for only 14000 rows which is way too high. Looking for possibility of optimizing it to somewhere around 50 ms.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I have also tried to comment out even the simple processing and measured only the value assignment to the row. Still, it take 2 mins.

Comment: I have edited to add my simple processing part as well

Comment: I have just loaded 14k rows into a DataTable with some columns. It took 25 milliseconds.

Comment: Is the other foreach (timeseries) loop inside that takes time.

Comment: Why do you always assign the dictionary to a variable in the loop? Does the property `sr.DatesValuesDic` something (expensive)? I wouldn't create a new variable at all or declare it before the loop.

Comment: Have you tried to run a profiler against the code? At least put a stopwatch in there and see which line is taking the longest to execute for each iteration.

Comment: @code4life I am using Stopwatch for For loop and for entire function. Let me do it for each line.

Comment: Which line is taking the longest to execute (and by how many milliseconds?) - I'm biasing against the nested iterative `Dictionary.TryGetValue` calls that you're making for each of the ~14k sortedDate members; wondering how much that is costing you.  Also, do you really need to parse the date? If it's from one date to another, it should be fine to just do direct assignment.

Comment: I have to do date time parsing because the input is of int type. I have now removed the Dictionary.TryGetValue and performance is much better (less than a min). I am planning to handle the Dictionary.TryGetValue situation at server end so I don't need to do this at front end.